# Get model object from api request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an api_view that is called from many modules.

```
url(r'^[0-9a-z\-]+/(?P<pk>[0-9a-z\-]+)/activate_entity/$', activate_entity)


@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def activate_entity(request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
```

What is the correct way to get the instance of the model object dynamically  inside activate_entity view without writing too many if statements? , for example i am calling it from module invoice

```
api/v1/invoice/8f9ef9aa-94ac-412d-ba9d-343a70b55a96/activate_entity/
api/v1/finance/1234f9aa-94ac-412d-ba9d-343a70b55a96/activate_entity/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
url(r'^(?P<entity>[0-9a-z\-]+)/(?P<pk>[0-9a-z\-]+)/activate_entity/$', activate_entity)
```

or even

```
url(r'^(?P<entity>(invoice|finance|...))/(?P<pk>[0-9a-z\-]+)/activate_entity/$', activate_entity)
```

or

```
path('<slug:entity>/<uuid:pk>/activate_entity/', activate_entity)
```

then

```
def activate_entity(request, entity, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    from django.apps import apps
    m = apps.get_model(app_label='my_app', model_name=entity)
    obj = m.objects.get(pk=pk)
    ...
```